# Setting reverse proxy in aws instance, running tomcat server

Tags: java, apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I am a newbie in AWS. I created an aws account (free tier) and launched an ec2 instance.
I have installed apache tomcat7 and mysql for hosting a web application.
The web application is created in Java (jsp pages).

Now I can access the web application using the url :
http://ec2-ipv4address-aws.com:8080/AppName/Login

My requirement is as follows:

```
 1. My friend have a domain example.com and we have created a subdomain business.example.com.
 2. We have redirected http://business.example.com to my web application deployed in tomcat listening to port 8080.
    So now we can access the web application using the url:
    http://business.example.com:8080/AppName/Login
 3. But our requirement is that when a user access http://business.example.com we need to show the Login page.
    Is this possible ?
```

I have researched and found something related to reverse proxy.
Some of the links says we need to set reverse proxy in apache config file.
I have tried to do this, but did not work.

Even though I am aware of deploying the application on tomcat webapps folder, I am not expert in advanced configuration modifications.

Anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

I am pasting my config changes in httpd.conf under VirtualHost tag:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName business.example.com
    ProxyRequests On

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>

    ProxyPass / http://ipv4address:8080/AppName/Login/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://ipv4address:8080/AppName/Login/

    <Location "/webapps">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

My httpd.conf file has the following sections commented:

```
#
# Allow remote server configuration reports, with the URL of
#  http://servername/server-info (requires that mod_info.c be loaded).
# Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.
#
#<Location /server-info>
#    SetHandler server-info
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
#    Allow from .example.com
#</Location>

#
# Proxy Server directives. Uncomment the following lines to
# enable the proxy server:
#
#<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
#ProxyRequests On
#
#<Proxy *>
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
#    Allow from .example.com
#</Proxy>
```

I am getting a page saying Error 502, Bad Gateway. Please check this url:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=19YT3_LnJuVznvMizPkqD0ppeuA_nSnTp

I have tried to redirect request received on port 80 to port 8080.
To add the iptables redirect rules, SSH to the server as root and executed the below commands:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Then saved the iptables using command : service iptables save

Also restarted iptables using command : service iptables restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, let's first try the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName business.example.com

ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/AppName/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/AppName/

</VirtualHost>
```

After this is applied, you should be able to open http://business.example.com/Login

Comment: Thank you very much. Happy to hear that I am on the right track. 
I have replaced the entry in my "httpd.conf" file. But it did not work. Do I have to wait for some time to reflect the changes. I have restarted apache using the command "service httpd restart".

Comment: Restarting apache is enough. What *exactly* happens in browser, do you get any error?

Comment: In browser, I get an Error 502, Bad Gateway.

Comment: Can you check if there is a entry in apache error log (usually in /var/log/httpd/ folder) that corresponds with your request

Comment: There is no errors shown for this in error_log file.
Here is the last few logs:
[Thu Nov 09 09:41:28 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...

[Thu Nov 09 09:41:28 2017] [notice] Digest: done

[Thu Nov 09 09:41:29 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: Anything in the access_log?

Comment: Nothing in access_log.

But one thing I have noted in httpd.conf file is some of the commented sections like "Proxy server directives". Do we need to uncomment those ?

Comment: The strange thing is that there is nothing in the logs, so I even suspect you are not even reaching this apache instance. What happens is you `service httpd stop` and then try again in the browser.

Comment: You can edit your original question to add more info, it is hard to read that in comment

Comment: I am running my web application in tomcat server.  So do we need to make any changes with its configurations ?
Because even after I stopped httpd service, I get the same error in browser for http://business.example.com and I could access the web application via http://ec2-ipv4address-aws.com:8080/AppName/Login

Comment: does `nslookup bussines.example.com` resolve to correct ec2 ipv4 address?

Comment: "nslookup business.example.com" shows two ipv4 addresses under the title "Non-authoritative answer".
I have tried this from my local machine as well as after logging in to ec2 instance. Both shows same ipv4 addresses, but it is not the ipv4 address of my ec2 instance.

Comment: But `http://business.example.com:8080/AppName/Login` still works, right? Is there any other AWS service involved except EC2 instance (like load balancer or elastic beanstalk)?

Comment: Yes, the url still works even after I stop httpd service (Apache tomcat7 is still running).
Also there are no load balancers or elastic beanstalk running. But there are more than one instance launched (obviously the ipv4 addresses will be different for each instance)

Comment: I am bit puzzled now :). How exactly did you execute this step `2.We have redirected http://business.example.com to my web application`?

Comment: A DNS record was added with following properties:
Zone: business,
Type: A,
TTL: auto,
Value: ipv4 address of ec2 instance.

Comment: Can you share the real hostname?

Comment: Ok.. The actual domain I want to make working is http://business.travistranslator.com.  The  web application I am hosting in amazon server can be accessed via  http://ec2-54-72-47-224.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/TravisBusiness/Login

Comment: DNS A record for your hostname does not point to EC2 IP address, so you did not do step 2. properly. Where exactly did you add that record?

Comment: I think DNS record added should be correct because the link http://business.travistranslator.com:8080/TravisBusiness/Login  is working.

I have even tried to redirect request received on port 80 to port 8080. But this didn't work for me.

Comment: Apparently there is some CloudFlare reverse proxy involved: If you open developer console in your browser and inspect response headers, you will see that response from `ec2-54..` has `Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1` and response from `bussines...` has `Server:cloudflare-nginx`. Double check your CloudFlare/DNS settings.

Comment: I could successfully make the url working for me... The ec2 instance in which tomcat is running was blocking the request to port 80.  I had to add an inbound rule to the security group of the instance to accept request on for 80.  Now your code works for me and web application can be accessed using the required url.... Thanks a lot for the help.